# Difference on .Count() in IQueryable and IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have list of object that I'm passing to function and inside I want to count them.
When I use IQueryable() it dosen't count them correct, but when I use IEnumerable() it count them Ok.

```
public int functCount(IQueryable<MyObject> myLisfOfObjects)  
{
    int numberOfItems = myListOfObjects.Count(o => o.isSet); //isSet is bool property in my object
    return numberOfItem;
}
```

On first call it return correct number of items, but when I change isSet properties in some elements in list it returns the same number as first call.

```
public int functCount(IEnumerable<MyObject> myLisfOfObjects)  
    {
        int numberOfItems = myListOfObjects.Count(o => o.isSet); //isSet is bool property in my object
        return numberOfItem;
    }
```

But when I change my code to this, it returns correct count every time.

Can anyone explain me the difference, and why is this happening?

Comment: Could you show how you call them, change their value and recall them, please ?  Hard to say with just the given code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since whatever you pass to either of those functions does not cause compilation errors, then it is safe to assume it is an `IQueryable`. Meaning that `.Count()` will be reevaluated as a SQL statement and run against the DB (ignoring whatever change you thought you have made in memory).
Calling `.Count()` on `IEnumerable` however is calling totally different method which will simply return the count of the in-memory collection.

In other words `IEnumerable<T>.Count()` and `IQueryable<T>.Count()` are two completely different methods, that do different things.